# Nginx - how to block endpoint by redirect to vue 403 page

Tags: vue.js, nginx, quasar-framework

Have a problem with vue/quasar framework with nginx as a host.

my standard endpoint looks like: exmaple.com/#/

I want to block exmaple.com/#/test by rerout this to 403. So in my nginx.conf I added like below:

```
    server {

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html$is_args$args;
        }

        location ^~ /test {
            deny all;
        }
    }
```

When I go to exmaple.com/#/test it simply passes me. But when I go to exmaple.com/test I get the 403. So it seems that the issue related to vue.js setup?

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Server side is unaware of #/ anchors, they exist only in a browser

Comment: ok, how can I solve this?

Comment: You can't. Is there a reason why you use exmaple.com/#/test hash routing and not exmaple.com/test ?